# How do i find the current open meeting item is cancel meeting item or deleted meeting item?

Tags: vba, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

How do i find the current open meeting item is cancel meeting item or deleted meeting item?

I need to find this via outlook object model.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance !

Comment: You can test the class of the meeting item to be: Request, Cancellation, ResponsePositive, ResponseNegative or ResponseTentative.  Or am I missing the point of your question?

Answer (score 0):

Class is described here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208118(v=office.12).aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/outlook-help/HV080804810.aspx

You will want olMeetingCancellation.